# transform value as array

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np

a = [0,np.array([1,2])]

try:
    # something like that
    [ x =  np.array([x]) for x in a if x == 0]
except ValueError:
    pass
```

I want to replace every zero value as an array, so my result would be:

`a = [np.array([0]), np.array([1,2])`

Comment: `a = [np.array([0]) if x is 0 else x for x in a]`

Comment: Hah @falsetru. Just noticed you got it first in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list comprehension is not valid.

Use:

```
x = [np.array([x]) for x in a if x == 0]
```

instead.

Do note that the logic here doesn't provide the relevant answer but rather:

```
x = array([1, 2])
```

in the end.

For what you're expecting:

Use:

```
np.array([0]) if x is 0 else x for x in a
```